# View controller deallocated but its viewDidUnload called because of low memory

Tags: ios

This is kinda fun.
I released a view controller(also removed its view from superview). But seconds later, the app crashes because of viewDidUnload called on this deallocated view controller (low memory).

How can I deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the object to nil.  When the viewDidUnload gets called, it will call release on nil, which is perfectly safe.  Also make sure to set the objects to nil in your viewDidUnload.  This will keep your dealloc from blowing up if called after a memory warning / viewDidUnload.